# koa.js streaming response from remote url

Tags: node.js, streaming, koa

I want to create a `koa` route that acts like a proxy for another url, which delivers a file that is usually a few dozens of Megabytes.

Therefore I would like not to block when making the response. I am using `this.body = yield request.get(url);` currently, where request is the `[co-request`][1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-request) module.

How do I stream the response back to the client ?

*Edit :*

I am now doing the following :

```
var req = require('request');
//...
this.body = req(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(this.params.what));
```

If I paste the `url` in my browser, I get a file just fine.
However if I get a `Error: Cannot pipe. Not readable.` in my route.

Comment: You were on the right track, but you just need to set `this.body` to a readable stream. Your answer (with the `request` module) works because `req(url)` returns a readable stream. In general, when you want to work with streams directly in Koa/co, you aren't going to be using `yield`.

Comment: @danneu that makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the solution was simply :

```
var req = require('request');
//...
this.body = req(url);
```

This is because `this.body` has to be a readable stream, which `req(url)` returns. Thanks to [@danneu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/511200/danneu) for the explanation.